# I coded my telegram bot (in python) prompting user to send an image. How do I make sure users only send image and nothing else?

Tags: python, image, bots, telegram

```
def process_color_step(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    product.color = message.text
    msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, 'ok, send me a photo of your phone')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg,process_image_step)

def process_image_step(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    product.image = message.photo[1].file_id
    msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Ok, send me a description of your phone?')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg,process_description_step)
```

Above is snippets of the code. The image file_id is passed on to product.image.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an image library to try to load the file. Something like [pillow](https://python-pillow.org/) would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use message handler as a list of handlers. for example in your conversation handler:

```
conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],
    states={
        PHOTO: [MessageHandler(Filters.photo, 'your function for getting photo),
                MessageHandler(Filters.all, 'your function for wrong entry),]
}
)
```

In this case if user update isn't photo, first MessageHandler for getting photo is not acceptable so handler try to catch next MessageHandler in the list:

```
MessageHandler(Filters.all, 'your function for wrong entry)
```

you have to define a function to response to user wrong entry and put it in second element of handlers list.